# Car Shaking at red light stop

Tags: honda, car, shaking

I have Honda accord 2013. 73000km on it. When I first turn the car on and the engine is cold, I can have the car stopped (in gear) and it will not shake. After the car has heated up, car begins to shake. If I turn the fan on, the shaking gets lower. In neutral or park the shaking diminishes.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When was the last time the vehicle was serviced (tuned up)? Is this a sudden issue or has it been progressively getting worse?

Comment: Do you notice any changes in the RPM while idling?

Comment: yes its come down. when I put fan or lights on rpm goes little up and shaking gets lower or close to stop

Answer (score 1):

Check if you RPM is going down when you are standing at the red light. If its below 600, then, the car's idle air control valve is not working properly or the throttle body is dirty. When you turn on the fan, this automatically kicks the RPM higher to for the little extra demand of power.

Answer (score 0):

Worn engine mounts?  try this if equipped with auto tranny. open the hood. one person starts engine; engage the e-brake and left foot pressing hard on the brake pedal. Put the car in drive gear and right foot blips the gas pedal.  The second person stands to the side of the open hood and watches if the engine jumps up and down.

Comment: That is possible, but bad motor (engine) mounts would allow the engine to shake all the time, not just when it is warm. How do you account for *"When I first turn the car on and the engine is cold, I can have the car stopped (in gear) and it will not shake"*?

Comment: engine cold means first 10-15 min. of driving is not shaking

Answer (score 0):

I get nervous when I'm at a red light stop too. Car is probably feeling the same :).

On a serious note, **I would start with cleaning the throttle body. Also check the condition of the air filter while you are at it.**  When the engine is cold, the idle is a bit high. As the car warms up, the idle speed lowers. This might explain why the car does not shake when cold.

Also when you put it in gear this engages the torque converter. This adds a slightly bit more strain on the engine and couple with the low idle causes the shaking.

I cannot explain why turning on the fan would help the situation. Does the car overheat?

Comment: no,  car is not overheat. I change the air filter, cabin filter and transmission fluid too

Comment: @SomeOne Well, throttle body is the next on the list. It's not very hard to clean and will not cost you a lot if you do it your self.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because Honda turns off some cylinders to achieve high gas mileage ratings. The vehicle essentially misfires by design. There is a class action lawsuit in the Central District of California right now for this exact issue.

Comment: This is wrong on a couple of fronts - the engines that quite a few manufacturers now make that shut down cylinders when not needed do **not** cause misfires. The class action states that over time, the shutdown could allow fouling to build up, but Honda expressly deny these claims and assertions .